# Jquery excel type dynamic formulas calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, excel, formulas

I am generating  **FINANCIAL ANALYSIS** and i generate dynamic formula for chart of accounts.

**Example**

1. Cash                   **-- Input able Field**
2. Short Term Investments **-- Input able Field**
3. Liquid Assets          **-- Formula Field** and i generate formula for this `@1~Cº + @2~Cº`
4. Notes Receivable       **-- Input able Field**
5. Accounts Receivable    **-- Input able Field**
6. Provision for Debts    **-- Input able Field**
7. Net Accounts Receivable **-- Formula Field** and i generate formula for this `@4~Cº + @5~Cº+@6~Cº`

and so on...

i am calculating on text box `focusout calculate_year`.

```
function calculate_year(ThisObj) {
            var obj;
            //intiate vaiables
            var year_formulaTxt = "",resultExp ="",lastPos ="",sequenceTypePosC="",sequenceTypePosP="",sequenceTypePosF="",COACode="",COAValue="",ratio_formulaTxt = "";
            var ratio_formulaTxt = "",COACode_P="",COAValue_Pyear_formula = "",ratio_formula = "",year_formulaObj = "",ratio_formulaObj = "",year_formulaArr = "",ratio_formulaArr = "",FormulaResult="";
            //match paterm for 
            var matchPattern = /[^\s()*/%+-/]+/g;
            var tableId =  $(ThisObj).closest('table').attr('id');
            var CuurentDiv = $(ThisObj).closest('.program-column').index();
             if (CuurentDiv < 2){   // to check if previous month added 
                     CuurentDiv = CuurentDiv + 1 ;
                }
            var tableIdNext =  $('.mCSB_container .program-column:eq('+CuurentDiv+') table').attr('id');

            //get all textbox inside div
            $('#'+tableId+' .financial_txt').each(function () {
                //º
                obj = $(this);

                year_formulaObj = obj.find('input[type=text]');
                ratio_formulaObj= obj.find('input[type=text]:eq(1)');

                //calcualtion for only formula fields
                if ($(year_formulaObj).attr('data-fieldtype') == "F") {

                    //get formula from custom field
                    year_formula = $(year_formulaObj).attr('year_formula');

                    if($.trim(year_formula) !=""){
                        //match formula with math's operator(Binary operator)
                        year_formulaArr =  year_formula.match(matchPattern);

                        //break string @ º : working for single experssion using loop
                        // ----------------------For Year ---------------------------
                        for( var i=0; i< year_formulaArr.length; i++ ){
                            //sub string from '@'  to 'º'
                            lastPos = year_formulaArr[i].substring(1, year_formulaArr[i].length - 1);

                            //all sequence type
                            sequenceTypePosC = lastPos.indexOf("C");
                            sequenceTypePosP = lastPos.indexOf("P");
                            sequenceTypePosF = lastPos.indexOf("F");//
                            if(sequenceTypePosC >= 0){
                            //console.log(lastPos);
                                //getting value of COACode From Formula
                                COACode = lastPos.substring(0, sequenceTypePosC - 1);

                                //getting value of COACode  From Text box id
                                COAValue = $.trim($('#'+tableId+' #txt_year_formula'+COACode).val()) == "" ? 0 : $.trim($('#'+tableId+' #txt_year_formula'+COACode).val());


                               $('#'+tableId+' #txt_year_formula'+COACode).val(COAValue);

                                //work for field value
                                 var tempRes = year_formula.substring(year_formula.indexOf("@"), year_formula.indexOf("º")+1);
                                year_formula = year_formula.replace(tempRes,COAValue);
                                tempRes = year_formula;
                                //replace rest of @ ,º with 0
                                tempRes = tempRes.replace(/\s*@[^º]+º\s*/g,parseFloat(0));

                                var result = parseFloat(mathEval(tempRes)).toFixed(3)|| 0;

                                $('#'+tableId+' #txt_year_formula'+$(this).attr('id')).val(mathEval(result) == "NaN" ?"0":mathEval(result));
                            }


                        }
                    }

               }

            });

        }
function mathEval (exp) {

                var reg = /(?:[a-z$_][a-z0-9$_]*)|(?:[;={}\[\]"'!&<>^\\?:])/ig,
                    valid = true;
                // Detect valid JS identifier names and replace them
                exp = exp.replace(reg, function ($0) {
                    // If the name is a direct member of Math, allow
                    if (Math.hasOwnProperty($0))
                        return "Math."+$0;
                    // Otherwise the expression is invalid
                    else
                        valid = false;
                });

                // Don't eval if our replace function flagged as invalid
                if (!valid){
                    //console.log("Invalid arithmetic expression");
                    }
                else{
                    try { return (eval(exp) == "Infinity" ? "0":eval(exp)); } catch (e) { };

                    }
        }
```

The String break and then generate calculation is best way on function `calculate_year` ?

As you seen i am calculating amount from dynamic formulas,the problem is that there is some formulas return me Infinity because of `tempRes.replace(/\s*@[^º]+º\s*/g,parseFloat(0));`

```
@8~Cº / @27~Cº
```

how i can handle this ?Sorry for English

[Working link](http://wellnessvisit.com/Risk%20Nucleus.html)

if you inspect you will see formula.